# Joining two models in a paginate

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have two tables that I want to join in the controller..

The paginate model also have a lot of conditions but I wanted to simplify it in here.

```
$Table = $this->Table->query('
 SELECT Table.id FROM Table
                INNER JOIN TableA ON Table.id = TableA.table_id
                INNER JOIN TableA.Table_id = TabelB.id
                WHERE 
                IFNULL(Table.x,0) <> 0
                GROUP BY Table.id
                HAVING COUNT(*) > 1');


$this->paginate = array(
'paramType' => 'querystring'
,'joins' => $Table
    )           
);
```

I'm nto that comfortable with Cake, coming more from a SQL background , but can this be done in the controller or is it that this should go in the Model ?

Comment: here i post a working example of bindModel with pagination witch is working for me match it with your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I answered in a identical question in "Controller pagination with a subquery" here's the same answer for this question

```
$this->paginate = array(
'paramType' => 'querystring',
'joins' => array(
    array(
    'table' => '(SELECT Table.id
                FROM Table 
                INNER JOIN TableA ON Table.id = TableA.Table_id
                INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.TableB_id = TableB.id
                WHERE 
                1 = 1
                GROUP BY Table.id
                HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)'
        'alias' => 'Table_x',
        'type' => 'INNER',
        'conditions' => array('Table_x.id = Table.id')
        )
    )
);


$Table = $this->paginate();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $UserId = $this->Auth->user(id);
$this->Rate->bindModel(array('belongsTo'=>array('Vehicle'=>array('className'=>'Vehicle','foreignKey'=>'vehicle_id'),),),false);

   $this->paginate = array('conditions'=>array('Rate.user_id'=>$UserId),
                        'order'     => array('Rate.created DESC'),
                        'limit'     =>'2'
                          );     
  $rating =  $this->paginate('Rate');
```